# Shopify: How to add custom field to admin blog create page?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am trying to add custom field like Video URL when creating a new blog in admin page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found this one.
https://help.advancedcustomfield.com/

Very good one for adding custom fields to products, collections, blogs as well as posts.
Thanks to great app makers!